# .jpeg filetype is not allowed in woocommerce upload

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website powered by WordPress + WooCommerce running the plugins **WooCommerce Uploads from wp fortune** to let my clients upload different things for the services that they purchase.

The problem is that they can upload jpg, png, pdf **but not .jpeg**

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, Just go to `wp-admin` then `Woocommerce - Upload My File` settings page and on allowed file types textbox just add `jpeg`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it was something like that, but it didn't take the general settings from woocommerce, insted it woorked with that change on every product page, and i dont have that many products so it went fast. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default .jpeg should be enabled, ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files

Within your *child theme* **functions.php** file, try pasting in this to enable the **jpeg**.

```
function my_child_theme_name_myme_types( $mime_types ) {
   $mime_types['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg';

   return $mime_types;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_child_theme_name_myme_types', 1, 1 );
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. I think that the problem is at the plugin